# SQL Server - query not showing rows where column value is null

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I have a Users table like this -

[Table View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lOvO3.jpg)

I am using the following query to retrieve rows where Faculty ID is CSE001, Designation is not student and User Role is not Marketing Coordinator -

[Query view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DsqBr.jpg)

But it's not giving me the result I need, cause the 2 rows I was expecting to have in return, has null in their UserRole column. So, it returns nothing.

[Query Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NFAyk.jpg)

So, how can I write the query, so that it returns me the rows even if they have null in UserRole column? Can anyone help me, please? Thanks...

Comment: NULL values are special values, you cannot use the usal equality operator "=" , "!=", and "<>". You must use the "IS NULL" and "IS NOT NULL" with those values.

Comment: Thanks Sir, for your kind reply. I get it now. :)

Answer (score 3):

Check for both Designation and UserRole if they contain NULL values.
Use IS NULL or IS NOT NULL for these kind of checks. This is because you cannot compare NULL with specific values.

```
SELECT * FROM Users
WHERE FacultyId = 'CSE001'
AND (Designation <> 'Student' OR Designation IS NULL)
AND (UserRole <> 'Marketing Coordinator' OR UserRole IS NULL)
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server, values can be missing but applicable, such as the value of a hair's color that has not been supplied for a person, or can be missing but inapplicable, such as the value for a bold person. In either case, SQL Server will mark missing values as NULL. A `NULL` is neither `TRUE`, nor `FALSE`, but `UNKNOWN`. This is the third value in **three-valued** logic. In other words, you can determine whether `X = Y` is TRUE or FALSE when you know the values of both `X` and `Y`, but what if `X` is missing? SQL Server will return `UNKNOWN`, marked as `NULL`. This is your case: you know that `Y` is known (equals 'Marketing Coordinator'), but `X` might be missing. Because `WHERE` returns only those rows which match the conditions (i.e. each predicate is evaluated as `TRUE`), `UNKNOWN` results will be filtered out.

You will need to write queries that use three-valued logic to account for three possible outcomes: `TRUE`, `FALSE` and `UNKNOWN`. In `ON`, `WHERE` and the `HEAVING` clauses, SQL Server will treat `NULL` as `FALSE`. On the other hand, `ORDER BY` sorts the `NULLs` together and first.

You can test for `NULL` values with `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL` operators rather than equal.

Answer (score 0):

You have explicitly ask for NULL values because they're quite special in relational databases.

This would be right one:

```
SELECT *
FROM Users
WHERE FacultyId <>'CSE001'
AND Designation <> 'Student'
AND (UserRole <> 'Marketing Coordinator' OR UserRole IS NULL);
```

Comment: I guess, It will be FacultyId='CSE001'. But, I can see what I did wrong... Thank You Sir, for your kind help... :)